# Vuex: How do I set an object in state to null?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a a Vuex store with a `user` object in state.

In my logout action, I am calling something more or less like this:

```
context.commit('setUser', null);
```

My mutation essentially calls `state.user = null` (not literally, just in this instance), but when I immediately call `console.log(state.user)`, it looks like nothing happened.

What is the "correct" way to completely clear an object in state?

Comment: This looks like it should work. Did you add the console.log to the setUser function?

Comment: Did you look at a store state in VueJS DevTools?

Comment: If you are using localStorage make sure you clear it after `context.commit('setUser', null);`. I made this mistake a couple of times

```context.commit("setUser", null);
localStorage.clear();```

Comment: I posted the answer to my own question if anyone is curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my own problem. In my `setUser` mutation, I was checking `if (typeof user === 'object') { ... }` before performing object-based logic. Well, it turns out that `typeof null` actually evaluates to `"object"` which is not at all what I was expecting. Today I learned JS is weird.

I have updated my check to `if (user === null && typeof user === 'object')`.